# Using "tail -f | grep" in script to simply show output

Tags: bash, grep, tail

I've been searching around online for a solution for what I want, however all solutions I found are using tail as a wrapper to wait for specific log events - I don't want that. I simply want to do this:

```
currentLog=$(ls -t /path/to/logs | head -n1)
tail -f $currentLog | grep $0
```

In a script. The purpose of having it in a script to begin with is because the script determines the most recent log file and hands it to the tail -f command. without a script, I have to manually determine the most recent log file. The script is simply acting as an easy way to have a grepped tail -f output on the most recent log file.

Desired output is what would happen if I ran the above commands manually in the shell. Actual output I am getting is NOTHING. Output is blank and it sits until I CTRL+C.

Note that I tried using the `grep --line-buffered` solution but it did not change anything.

Comment: If you just want to show the output, use cat instead of tail.

Comment: It should work but there are 2 potential problems here - 0. you shouldn't parse output of `ls` - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead 1. what is `$0` supposed to mean here? Positional arguments are counted from 1.

Comment: So debug the script. Check if `currentLog` is good path. Check if `$0` content is right (why `$0`?). Do `set -x` and check if correct processes are beeing run from your script with correct arguments. On the last resort you could `stdbuf -oL tail -f "$currentLog" | stdbuf -oL grep --line-buffered "$0"` but I don't think it would help.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
currentLog=$(find /path/to/logs -type f -mtime -1 -print -quit)
tail -f "$currentLog" | grep -Ei '(.*)(Expression)(.*)'
```

It worked for me, when I tried it on /var/log.

Let me know!

Comment: I assume that using find instead of ls is more preferred. I will check the link that  Arkadiusz Drabczyk to read up about why not to use ls for parsing info.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you kindly for your responses. The issue was in fact that I was using $0. Changed to $1 and it worked as expected. This question is misleading now that the answer has nothing to do with tail or grep...